# Why does Django recreate the DB tables on each docker-container restart?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose, django-migrations, drop-table

I am running Django with PostgreSQL in a docker-compose setup for development. Each time I restart the application container, the database is empty, even though I do neither restart the DBMS container nor do I drop the DBMS's data volume. It seems that Django is dropping all tables upon restart. Why?

My setup closely follows the description [here](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/). That is, my compose file looks as follows (simplified):

```
version: '3.8'

services: 
    
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_dev
      - POSTGRES_USER=dev
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: app-data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  app:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8888
    container_name: app
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL
      - PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    volumes:
      # Mount the local source code folder for quick iterations.
      # See: https://www.docker.com/blog/containerized-python-development-part-3/
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /code
    ports:
      - target: 8888
        published: 8888
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - ./dev.env

volumes:
    app-data:
      external: true
```

The Django application is started by means of an `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgresql" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

doMigrate=${DB_MIGRATE:-false}
if [ "$doMigrate" = true ] ;
then
  python manage.py flush --no-input
  python manage.py migrate
fi

exec "$@"
```

In the development setup, I set `DB_MIGRATE=true` and `DEBUG=1`.

Comment: Simple volume description works for me in this case: ```volumes: - app-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data```

Comment: @AndreyBorzenko, I changed the `volumes` statement, but to no avail. I also set `DB_MIGRATE` to `false` and disabled the `DEBUG` mode. Still, when I do a `docker-compose restart` on the `app` container, the DB is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django `flush` command removes all data from the database, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-flush).

Hence, to solve my problem above, I only need to remove the line

```
  python manage.py flush --no-input
```

from my `entrypoint.sh` script.

Explanation: I thought - incorrectly - that `flush` would commit any pending transactions that might still be open from other applications that might potentially use the DB. This is not the case. Instead, `flush` simply removes all data.